# Delphi isNumber

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

Is there a method in Delphi to check if a string is a number without raising an exception?

its for int parsing.

and an exception will raise if one use the

```
try
  StrToInt(s);
except
  //exception handling
end;
```

Comment: What is "infinite exceptions"?

Comment: By number you mean integer? Or do you want to allow real numbers as well?

Comment: Is the number in the string required to be a number that can be stored by a Delphi numeric type? Nineteen quintillion is a number, but it won't fit in any Delphi integral type. One hundred-thousandth is a number, but no Delphi numeric type can hold it.

Comment: @Rob Kennedy:  `if Application.MessageBox('Is this a number?'#13#10+str, MB_YESNO + MB_ICONQUESTION + MB_DEFBUTTON1) = IdYes then ShowMessage(str +' IS a number!') else ShowMessage('Sorry.  ''+str+'' doesn't seem to be a number...');`

Comment: @Jørn, it was a serious question. I'm just trying to stave off the embarrassment of displaying a nonsense error message like "19000000000000000 is not a number."

Comment: @Rob Kennedy:  Aha (blush), I thought you meant `str:='Nineteen quintillion'`, and not `str:='19000000000000000000'`...  In either case, my silly solution was meant to be humorous.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

```
var
  s: String;
  iValue, iCode: Integer;
...
val(s, iValue, iCode);
if iCode = 0 then
  ShowMessage('s has a number')
else
  ShowMessage('s has not a number');
```

Comment: The advantage of this solution is that it works for real numbers as well. For the price of being a lot harder to read than `TryStrToInt`. And it requires at least two local variables.

Comment: @none: `TryStrToInt` should be available in D7. Any reason why you accepted this solution and not the one posted by bassfriend?

Comment: @Smasher @none `TryStrToInt` is in D7, as well as its friends `TryStrToInt64`, `TryStrToBool`, `TryStrToFloat`, `TryStrToCurr`, `TryStrToDate`, `TryStrToTime` and `TryStrToDateTime`. Seems to me that the OP has accepted the wrong answer.

Comment: You should be aware that Val supports hexadecimal numbers starting with 0x or $, which may or may not be what you need. Following two lines will both put '16' into 'i'.  
   Val('$10', i, c);
   Val('0x10', i, c);

Comment: I do not like this solution because it will leave you a hint that iValue is not used.

Comment: Val('5123456789', c, k); Will return error code "10" in k, in other words, the 10th character does not fit into the integer. Keep that in mind please, val is only suited for integers not longint. Use TryStrToInt64 if you suspect the string may contain a number greater than int. However.... TryStrToInt64 only returns the first numbers until it finds a non number - so "12345abc6778" will return 12345. Which is probably not what you want either.

Answer (score 69):

function [TryStrToInt](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/SysUtils_TryStrToInt.html)(const S: string; out Value: Integer): Boolean;

> TryStrToInt converts the string S, which represents an integer-type number in either decimal or hexadecimal notation, into a number, which is assigned to Value. If S does not represent a valid number, TryStrToInt returns false; otherwise TryStrToInt returns true.
>
> To accept decimal but not hexadecimal values in the input string, you may use code like this:

```
function TryDecimalStrToInt( const S: string; out Value: Integer): Boolean;
begin
   result := ( pos( '$', S ) = 0 ) and TryStrToInt( S, Value );
end;
```

Comment: `TryStrToInt` returns true even for `xFF`, not only `$FF`.

Answer (score 19):

Try this function `StrToIntDef()`

From help

Converts a string that represents an integer (decimal or hex notation) to a number with error default.

Pascal

```
function StrToIntDef(const S: string; Default: Integer): Integer;
```

**Edit**

Just now checked the source of `TryStrToInt()` function in Delphi 2007. If Delphi 7 dont have this function  you can write like  this. Its just a polished code to da-soft answer

```
function TryStrToInt(const S: string; out Value: Integer): Boolean;
var
  E: Integer;
begin
  Val(S, Value, E);
  Result := E = 0;
end;
```

Comment: This is a good option **IF** there is an obvious default value that actually makes sense. If only used to check whether the result is -1 afterwards (for example), `TryStrToInt` is a lot more robust and readable.

Comment: A useful function, but not addressing the question as asked. There is no way to tell whether or not the input was a number.

Comment: @David: Yes you are correct but i just want to suggest an alternative which will help the user to set some default value also

Comment: understood, I was just making the point for the benefit of the OP so that he was aware of the issue

Comment: @David: There is a possibility. A string `test` contains a valid integer number **iff** `StrToIntDef(test,-1) = StrToIntDef(test,0)`, accompanied by the test for leading `'$'` chars. I would not advocate that solution, but it *is* possible.

Comment: StrToInt / StrToIntDef can not handle longint though. Can it?

Comment: @Bharat Delphi 7 does have `TryStrToInt()`

Answer (score 10):

XE4 and newer:

```
for ch in s do
   TCharacter.IsNumber(ch);
```

Don't forget:

```
uses System.Character
```

Comment: Of course: this fails on negative numbers and those with a leading `+`. I'm surprised how many answers don't think of negative numbers.

Answer (score 3):

In delphi 7 you can use the `Val` procedure. From the help:

*Unit:* System
*Delphi syntax:* `procedure Val(S; var V; var Code: Integer);`

S is a string-type expression; it must be a sequence of characters that form a signed real number.

V is an integer-type or real-type variable. If V is an integer-type variable, S must form a whole number.

Code is a variable of type Integer.

If the string is invalid, the index of the offending character is stored in Code; otherwise, Code is set to zero. For a null-terminated string, the error position returned in Code is one larger than the actual zero-based index of the character in error.

Answer (score 3):

use this function

```
function IsNumber(N : String) : Boolean;
var
I : Integer;
begin
Result := True;
if Trim(N) = '' then
 Exit(False);

if (Length(Trim(N)) > 1) and (Trim(N)[1] = '0') then
Exit(False);

for I := 1 to Length(N) do
begin
 if not (N[I] in ['0'..'9']) then
  begin
   Result := False;
   Break;
 end;
end;
```

end;

Comment: Awful: why using `Trim()` when still checking every character? Why using `Break` and not `Exit` as previously? Why not setting `Result := True` at the end and assume failure from the very start? It also doesn't allow negative Integers or Integers with a leading `+`, which is legal and must be expected. The bad indention and post formatting fit the code quality.

Comment: Result:= True is in the first line, Trim() is useful if we have much white space at the beginning and end and for the positive and negative signs you must develop the function ..  @AmigoJack

Comment: `Trim()` is not useful at all (especially done again and again) when a check would already fail at the first character. Only the end needs `true` while multiple other options all result in `false`, hence setting the former as default is more logical. "_You must develop the function_" could have been the intro of your answer right away. Without any code.

Answer (score 2):

For older Delphi versions from delphi 5 help example:

```
uses Dialogs;
var 

  I, Code: Integer;
begin
  { Get text from TEdit control }
  Val(Edit1.Text, I, Code);
  { Error during conversion to integer? }
  if Code <> 0 then
    MessageDlg('Error at position: ' + IntToStr(Code), mtWarning, [mbOk], 0);
  else
    Canvas.TextOut(10, 10, 'Value = ' + IntToStr(I));   
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

In some languages decimal separators are different (for example, '.' is used in English and ',' is used in Russian). For these cases to convert string to real number the following procedure is proposed:

```
function TryStrToFloatMultiLang(const S : String; out Value : Extended) : Boolean;
var
  dc : char;
begin
  Result := false;
  dc := DecimalSeparator;
  DecimalSeparator := '.';
  try
    Result := TryStrToFloat(S, Value);
  except
    DecimalSeparator := ',';
    Result := TryStrToFloat(S, Value);
  end;
  DecimalSeparator := dc;
end;
```

**Update**

As @Pep mentioned TryStrToFloat catch exceptions, but it returns boolean value. So the correct code is:

```
function TryStrToFloatMultiLang(const S : String; out Value : Extended) : Boolean;
var
  dc : char;
begin
  Result := false;
  dc := DecimalSeparator;
  DecimalSeparator := '.';
  Result := TryStrToFloat(S, Value);
  if not Result then begin
    DecimalSeparator := ',';
    Result := TryStrToFloat(S, Value);
  end;
  DecimalSeparator := dc;
end;
```

Comment: While the remark about different decimal separators is definitively important, your sample code is trying to catch exceptions where there are not exceptions, because TryStrToFloat already catches any possible exception.  This means that your "except" clause is never executed.  "Good catch!", you might think :)

Answer (score 0):

When you using procedure

> val(s, i, iCode);

and set value xd ....

> val('xd', i, iCode)

as a result we obtain: 13

Answer (score -2):

standard unit Variants

```
function VarIsNumeric(v:Variant):Boolean
```

Comment: This tells you the type of the variant, not whether a string contains a number.

Comment: Although it doesn't answer the question, it's still good to know it exists. Thanks mate!